OpenRC service needs password to unlock certificate
I'm making my own service which communicates using sockets and SSL. It needs a certificate to work, but the certificate is currently locked behind a password.
I can think of two ways to fix this. Either make the certificate not require a password. Or store the password to the certificate in a separate file, which the service can read in order to unlock the certificate.
Both options feel like a bad idea. What is best practice here?
Also, I'm using OpenRC not systemd.

Check keycloack , it can store password and extract it on more secure way :)

Which socket (port numbers are important)? What does "locked behind a password" mean?  What are the commands and error messages involved?

This isn't openRC or systemd related. It's a function of security: You can have a certificate which requires a manually entered password to unlock, or you can have a service that comes up automatically on boot. You cannot do both and any attempt to have your cake and eat it will ultimately wind up being less secure than just having the private cert passwordless but only readable by the application that needs to read it.

I also feel that you should ask this question on our sister site, https://security.stackexchange.com/ and leave off the openRC part, because you'll get a much better answer and explanation there.

I’m voting to close this question because this question should really be on security.se


in a separate file, which the service can read in order to unlock the certificate.

Well, that's not a good solution, because if you assume you can make that password safe unreadable from other parties, you can do the same to the certificate, and wouldn't have a problem in the first place.
You're right to feel that both options are suboptimal, because they give access to the (unencrypted) certificate at rest (one would argue you'd have full-disk encryption if this is your worry, but that just "shifts the same problem further down the line). At runtime, the problem is there, anyway: if you assume your system has no surprising security failures, then only root (or the specifically assigned owner of that file) could read your unencrypted certificate from the file. And root could just as well attach a debugger to the service, to read the certificate straight from process memory, where it has to sit.
So,

an unauthorized party gets root access to your machine while it's running: lost with either solution, plus lost with any other solution as well, because key must be in memory of operating service, and root can read that.
no unauthorized party can read files that aren't owned by them: you're safe in either case

The only solution here is to not give the computer access to the secret key material at all, which leads to hardware security modules, or at least enclave computing – both probably out of reach for your application.
You should really read Kiyomizu's answer on how to at least mitigate the risk that some cloud VM image gets abused as means of getting access to the certificate unnoticed.

HashiCorp Vault, AWS Secrets Manager, Google Cloud Secret Manager, or LINUX's keyctl securely store and manage sensitive information with encryption, access control, and audit logging.
Removing the password from a certificate is not recommended for high-security use, as it exposes the private key. Instead, use OpenSSL’s Passphrase File or OpenRC for secure initialization. These methods help manage secrets safely without storing them in plain text or compromising security. For critical use cases, integrate with a dedicated secrets management system to handle sensitive data securely at runtime.

this is a very valid recommendation – having a cloud image with the secrets in it lying around gives way more chance for human error / maliciousness to give something access to the certificate in undetected ways than if each time the certificate is loaded, it needs to be loaded from a central service that logs these accesses. +1!

What is "OpenSSL's Passphrase File"?

I use an OpenSSL passphrase file to securely store the passphrase for decrypting private keys,  Allows automated tasks like certificate signing /  key deployment to run without manual input.
